# How to Disable HTML submit Button Background

Tags: html, forms, button

I used HTML form, in that form I used a Button tag for submit.

Image is showing some background, I  set background as transperent but it is still showing something.

I want to totally remove background.

```
<button type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
<img src="/images/Btn.PNG" width="90" heght="50" alt="submit" />
```

Comment: I don't see it, but if you mean that part of the button is visible around the image (I see that by giving it another background colour), you can set its padding to 0.

Comment: Oh, and Firefox's infernal "-moz-inner-focus". Or, use an `<input type="image">`.

Comment: @above in all browsers showing same

Comment: @Lister padding also not working

Answer (score 0):

Why use a button ?

you can :

html :

```
<form id="myFormID" ... >
     ...
    <img src="..." onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>
```

javascript :

```
function myFunction()
{
     //MakeYourTest
     $('#myFormID').submit(); //This line will commit your form
}
```

and you can do what you want in your javascript code

Comment: That would make the functionality depend on JavaScript.

Comment: Your function can just validate the form.
as :

$('#myFormId').submit(); with jQuery

Comment: hmmm looks ok, can you please give me full example of usbmit a form using that onlick()

Comment: i explain it on a comment before, but i'll write you a full example. EDIT: Look my answer